# OpenGL ES 2.0 Slight Hiccup Android, 1.0 Smooth

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, render, visual-glitch

I am constantly getting 60 frames per second and doing no CPU intensive operations on a simple application displaying a single rotating triangle.  Unfortunately, when using OpenGL ES 2.0 on a Samsung Galaxy Express I am recieving slight hiccups in the rendering, as if some frames are not being drawn.

The funny thing is that with OpenGL ES 1.0 there is no such hiccup, so I know it does not have to do with the rotation method or the use of System.nanoTime () as a measure of the elapsed time between frames. I use the exact same method I both, and as per my research here and with "fixing your timestep" have smoothed the game loop. I get the same results.

To make matters even funnier, the spinning triangle example from Google's own developer.android.com introduction to OpenGL has the same issue, as well as the Play Store examples from the website 'learnopengles' both of which are rendering a simple spinning triangle.

As per research into similar threads here, I have tried continuous rendering as well as dirty rendering. The slight flicker remains.

After 3 days I am wondering whether it is my device, or whether all OpenGL ES 2.0 applications have a slight stutter that is more easily noticeable on a single spinning triangle.

I have no other test device and no money for one, so I cannot say whether it is a problem with my device,  or the Samsung Galaxy Express in general, or something else.

Is there anything else I can do to fix this issue?
Is this slight stutter normal behavior?
Are there any examples of code I can test myself that does not exhibit this behavior?
Does the Samsung Galaxy express have a known issue with OpenGL 2?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Do you use single or double buffering?

Comment: Hello mr5, thanks for the comment.  As far as I know (and I am new to Android) I am using double buffering.  Android controls through the GLSurfaceView method onDrawFrame when I am allowed to draw to what I believe is the back buffer in a double buffered system.

Comment: Did you eventually fix your problem ?